# Invalid init of non-const reference of type std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator& from rvalue of type std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm get the above error when I compile the following [MWE](http://rextester.com/IQGJG47548) on GCC

```
#include <string>

void frobnigate( const std::string& str )
{
    std::string::const_iterator& iter = str.begin();
}

int main()
{
    frobnigate( "all things!!!" );
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a GCC issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong or is this a GCC issue?

Yes you are doing something wrong.

[`std::string::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin) returns a [value type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) (*rvalue*, since its a temporary). But you are trying to initialize a non-const reference from an *rvalue* which is illegal in C++.

You definitely want:

```
std::string::const_iterator iter = str.begin();
```

Better still:

```
auto iter = str.begin();
```

---

Iterators are cheap to copy and should be used by value, so a reference or const-reference to an iterator is frowned upon.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this:

```
std::string::const_iterator iter = str.begin();
```

That is, remove the reference, because `begin()` returns a value, not a reference, and you need to manage the lifetime of that iterator (which will be a simple, small, cheap value such as a pointer).